# how to set timer for online examination system

Tags: javascript, timer

I am trying to set a timer for my online exam. the timer duration should be 10 minutes.but below code giving me 2 minutes only.
kindly provide me the code to set timer duration of 10 minutes or just guide me where I need to alter the code

CODE OF TIMER::

```
//***********************************************//
//* Online Examination System                   *//
//*---------------------------------------------*//

function countDown() {
      sec--;
  if (sec == -01) {
    sec = 59;
    min = min - 1;
    if(min==-01)
        {
            min=59;
            hour=hour-1;
        }else
            {
                hour=hour;
            }
  } else {
   min = min;
  }
if (sec<=9) { sec = "0" + sec; }

  time = (hour<=9 ? "0" + hour : hour) + " : " + (min<=9 ? "0" + min : min) + " : " + sec + "";
if (document.getElementById) { document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = time; }
  SD=window.setTimeout("countDown();", 1000);
if (hour=='00'&& min == '00' && sec == '00') { sec = "00";min="00"; window.clearTimeout(SD); window.location=document.forms[0].action+"?fs=yes";}
}

function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

addLoadEvent(function() {
  countDown();
});
```

Comment: If it's for an online exam you should try it by yourself since your are learning...if people give you the solution you won't learn anything !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following fiddle, Just now I created for you.[my timer](http://jsfiddle.net/r9asnh0p/)

```
var time = 600;
callsetTimeOut();  

function callsetTimeOut(){
  setTimeout(function(){
  if(time){
  time--;
  var min = Math.floor(time/60),sec= Math.round(time%60);
   document.getElementById("info2").innerHTML =min +":" + sec + " min left";
   callsetTimeOut();
  }min +"Min Left"
  }, 1000);
}
<div id="info2"></div>
```